# Concat multiple CSV's with the same column name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, export-to-csv

Im having trouble with concatting these pandas dataframes as I keep getting a error saying `pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` I am also trying to make my code less clunky and run smoother. I was also wondering if there was a way to get multiple pages on one csv using python. Any help would be great.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

URL = "https://www.collincad.org/propertysearch?situs_street=Willowgate&situs_street_suffix" \
      "=&isd%5B%5D=any&city%5B%5D=any&prop_type%5B%5D=R&prop_type%5B%5D=P&prop_type%5B%5D=MH&active%5B%5D=1&year=2021&sort=G&page_number=1"

t = URL + "&page_number="
URL2 = t + "2"
URL3 = t + "3"

s = requests.Session()

data = []

page = s.get(URL,headers=headers)
page2 = s.get(URL2, headers=headers)
page3 = s.get(URL3, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content, "lxml")
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3.content, "lxml")


for row in soup.select('#propertysearchresults tr'):
    data.append([c.get_text(' ',strip=True) for c in row.select('td')])
for row in soup2.select('#propertysearchresults tr'):
    data.append([c.get_text(' ',strip=True) for c in row.select('td')])
for row in soup3.select('#propertysearchresults tr'):
    data.append([c.get_text(' ',strip=True) for c in row.select('td')])


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data[2:], columns=data[1])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data[3:], columns=data[2])

final = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0)

final.to_csv('Street.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Your data variable already has all three pages worth of the table cells, right? So… it’s already “concatenated”, right? I think the only thing you need to do is drop any headers from tables on pages 2 & 3 that were appended along with the real data, or maybe be more selective in your td-iterator and make sure to avoid the first rows in pages 2 & 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What happens?

As mentioned @Zach Young `data` is already holding all the rows you like to convert into **one** dataframe. So it is not an issue of `pandas` it is more an issue on how collecting the information.

#### How to fix?

An approach based on the code in your question is selecting the table data more specific - Note the `tbody` in the selection, this will exclude the headers:

```
for row in soup.select('#propertysearchresults tbody tr'):
    data.append([c.get_text(' ',strip=True) for c in row.select('td')])
```

While creating your dataframe you can set the column headers additionally:

```
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[c.get_text(' ',strip=True) for c in soup.select('#propertysearchresults thead td')])
```

#### Example

This will show how to iterate the different pages of website containing your tables:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

URL = "https://www.collincad.org/propertysearch?situs_street=Willowgate&situs_street_suffix" \
      "=&isd%5B%5D=any&city%5B%5D=any&prop_type%5B%5D=R&prop_type%5B%5D=P&prop_type%5B%5D=MH&active%5B%5D=1&year=2021&sort=G&page_number=1"

s = requests.Session()

data = []
while True:

    page = s.get(URL,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

    for row in soup.select('#propertysearchresults tbody tr'):
        data.append([c.get_text(' ',strip=True) for c in row.select('td')])

    if (a := soup.select_one('#page_selector strong + a')):
        URL = "https://www.collincad.org"+a['href']
    else:
        break


pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[c.get_text(' ',strip=True) for c in soup.select('#propertysearchresults thead td')])
```

#### Output

|  | Property ID ↓ Geographic ID ↓ | Owner Name | Property Address | Legal Description | 2021 Market Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2709013 R-10644-00H-0010-1 | PARTHASARATHY SURESH & ANITHA HARIKRISHNAN | 12209 Willowgate Dr Frisco, TX 75035 | Ridgeview At Panther Creek Phase 2, Blk H, Lot 1 | $513,019 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 61 | 2129238 R-4734-00C-0110-1 | HEPFER ARRON | 990 Willowgate Dr Prosper, TX 75078 | Willow Ridge Phase One, Blk C, Lot 11 | $509,795 |

Answer (score 1):

Usually one would loop through the page numbers and concat a list of dataframes, but if you only have three pages, your code is ok.

Because `for row in ...` is always writing to `data`, your final dataframe is df1, but you just need to drop the *column-named* rows.

```
final = df1[df1['Property ID ↓ Geographic ID ↓']!='Property ID ↓ Geographic ID ↓']
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than your last several lines of code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data[2:], columns=data[1])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data[3:], columns=data[2])

final = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0)

final.to_csv('Street.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

You can use this (which avoids slicing into different dataframes and concatenation):

```
final = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])   # Sets the first row as the column names
final = final.iloc[:,1:]   # Gets rid of the additional index column
```